# react - Navlink style by styled-components

Tags: reactjs, routes, styled-components

[image]
[image]
i made a Navlink by styled-components named StyledLink
i want to set transform when link is actived

```
&.active { 
      border-bottom:3px black solid;
      font-weight:bold;
      opacity:1;
    }
```

now it works but, when i enter other links then home link is always actived too
i want to inactive home

i'm sorry i'm not good at english :(

```
import React from 'react'
import {Link as RouterLink, NavLink} from 'react-router-dom'
import styled from 'styled-components'

const StyledLink = styled(NavLink)`
    padding:10px 0px;
    margin : 0px 10px;
    opacity:0.6;
    color:black;
    font-family:'RIXGOL';
    text-decoration: none;
    &:hover {
        border-bottom:3px black solid;
        font-weight:bold;
        opacity:1;
    }
    &.active { 
      border-bottom:3px black solid;
      font-weight:bold;
      opacity:1;
    }
`

const HomeLink = styled(NavLink)`
    padding:10px 0px;
    margin : 0px 10px;
    opacity:0.6;
    color:black;
    font-family:'RIXGOL';
    text-decoration: none;
    &:hover {
        border-bottom:3px black solid;
        font-weight:bold;
        opacity:1;
    }
    &.active { 
      border-bottom:3px black solid;
      font-weight:bold;
      opacity:1;
    }
`

export default function Nav() {
  return (
    <div style={{marginBottom:'10px', padding:'10px'}}>
        <HomeLink to='/'>home</HomeLink>
        <StyledLink to='/pvp'>pvp</StyledLink>
        <StyledLink to='/championship'>world</StyledLink>
    </div>
  )
}
```

i tried to make new style components but it doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you're looking for a way to style the current active link.
Whenever you click another link, the &:active styling is still applied.
I had the same issue, but found a work-around by using the following:

```
import { NavLink, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

const { pathname } = useLocation();
console.log(pathname);
const Menu = [
    {
        titel: "Home",
        link: "/"
    },
    {
        titel: "PvP",
        link: "/pvp"
    },
    {
        titel: "Worlds",
        link: "/championship"
    }
];

{Menu.map((item) => {
  if (pathname == item.link)
    return (
        <NavLink className="navbar-link active-link" to={item.link}>
        {item.titel}
      </NavLink>
    )
  else return (
    <NavLink className="navbar-link" to={item.link}>
    {item.titel}
  </NavLink>
  
  )
})}

.navbar-link {
  border-bottom:3px black solid;
  font-weight:bold;
  opacity:1;
}

.active-link {
padding:10px 0px;
  margin : 0px 10px;
  opacity:0.6;
  color:black;
  font-family:'RIXGOL';
  text-decoration: none;
  &:hover {
      border-bottom:3px black solid;
      font-weight:bold;
      opacity:1;
  }
}
```

I do wanna note, that I kept my CSS in a separate file, but just use the same in-line styling if you wish so.